# Find Sum of cashbonus on the basis of user id in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
ub_referrerid  ub_redeemerid  ub_referrer_cashbonus    ub_redeemer_cashbonus
   186           190              100                            60
   154           186              100                            60
   190           201              100                            60
   154           189              100                            60
   190           211              100                            60
   154           255              100                            60
   190           297              100                            60
```

Now I have To Find The Sum Of cash Bonus on the basis of userid
suppose I have userid 154 which is present in both `ub_referrerid` and  `ub_redeemerid` now I have to find the sum of userid 154 from column `ub_referrer_cashbonus` and  `ub_redeemer_cashbonus` using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create a CTE with UNION ALL two queries : one for referers bonuses and one for referees bonuses.
We then amalgamate the results.

> ```
> create table ub(
>   ub_referrerid int,
>   ub_redeemerid int,
>   ub_referrer_cashbonus int,   
>   ub_redeemer_cashbonus int);
> insert into ub values
>  (186 ,190 ,100, 60 ),
> (154 ,186, 100 ,60 ),
> (190 ,201 ,100, 60 ),
> (154 ,189 ,100, 60),
> ( 190 ,211, 100, 60 ),
> (154 ,255 ,100 ,60),
> ( 190 ,297 ,100, 60);
>    
> with bonus as (
> select 
>    ub_referrerid id ,
>    sum(ub_referrer_cashbonus) referBonus,
>    0 redbonus
> from 
>    ub
> group by
>    ub_referrerid
> union all 
> select 
>    ub_redeemerid id,
>    0 refCash,
>    sum(ub_redeemer_cashbonus) redCash
> from 
>    ub
> group by
>    ub_redeemerid
> )
> select
>    b.id ,
>    sum(b.referbonus) refBonus,
>    sum(b.redBonus) redbonus,
>    sum(b.referBonus)+sum(redBonus) total
> from bonus b
> group by id 
> order by id ;
> ```

> ```
>  id | refBonus | redbonus | total
> --: | -------: | -------: | ----:
> 154 |      300 |        0 |   300
> 186 |      100 |       60 |   160
> 189 |        0 |       60 |    60
> 190 |      300 |       60 |   360
> 201 |        0 |       60 |    60
> 211 |        0 |       60 |    60
> 255 |        0 |       60 |    60
> 297 |        0 |       60 |    60
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=62fc4760a1ba637e0b819ae4729dbf5f)*

Comment: thats right answer thanku

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GROUP BY clause based on ub_referrerid and ub_redeemerid with same alias userid. Then use UNION ALL (In this operation, column names with alias must be same).

```
SELECT   userid,SUM(bonus) AS bonus
FROM
(
SELECT   ub_referrerid as userid,
         (ub_referrer_cashbonus+ub_redeemer_cashbonus) as bonus
FROM     YOUR_TABLE_NAME
UNION ALL
SELECT   ub_redeemerid as userid,
         (ub_referrer_cashbonus+ub_redeemer_cashbonus) as bonus
FROM     YOUR_TABLE_NAME
)        CASH
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY userid;
```

Comment: i want the sum of user id 186 which is 360